# Insert the value of the foreign key ID and not the ID

Tags: database, vb.net

I am having a problem with VB.net & databases, which is when inserting data into table, I need to insert the value of the foreign key and not the key itself.

For Example I Have TWO Tables: Employee, Department.

With the following Model

```
Department (DepID pk, DepName)
Employee (EmpID pk, EmpName, DepID fk)
```

When Inserting data into Employee using  vb winform,

I need to insert (or choose from combo) the DepName  in the place of DepID….

NB1: That I could so easily with MS Access Forms using column count & Width.

NB2: I can select the  data this way, But I am talking about manipulating data, like Insert, Update, Delete…

Comment: a control like a Dept CBO can be bound to a datasource and then DisplayMember and ValueMember are used to control what displays and the value of the selected item.

Comment: That only works if I only want this value to be independant
but in my case, I am inserting related values

Comment: And According to the modeling & relations, the data type od DepID in the employee table is Number, not text..

Comment: perhaps you could add some code to show what you are after, because the title doesnt make much sense.  If you pick a Dept from a CBO do you not want that DeptID (PK) to be stored as the DeptID (FK) in the Employee table?

Comment: I am intending to do it with GUI with the minimum possible code

I dont know if you are familiar with this option in MS Access..

What is needed, is to allow the user to choose the DepName when inserting new Employee.. and not the ID,, because the user should not see ID, and even will not know each DepID belongs to which depName

and yes, DEPID pk should be stored as FK in employee, but the user should see the depName instead, not NUMBER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`What is needed, is to allow the user to choose the DepName when inserting new Employee.. and not the ID`
this is **precisely** the functionality you get from a bound control using `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`:

```
    Dim SQL As String = "Select * FROM Department ORDER BY DeptName"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, dbCon)
        myDS = New DataSet("Dept")
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(myDS, "Dept")

        frmM.cboDept.DisplayMember = "DeptName"   ' what to SHOW
        frmM.cboDept.ValueMember = "DeptID"       ' value to track
        frm.cboDept.DataSource = myDS.Tables(0)
    End Using
```

You can add adapters and such to the form to skip the code.  Each item in the CBO will be a database row object, but the control will display data from the column indicated by `DisplayMember`, In this case, "DeptName"

To get the value, that is the DeptID:

```
Private Sub cboDept_SelectedValueChanged(sender, e ...) 
    myEmployee.DeptID = Convert.ToInt32(cboDept.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Using the ValueMember property, we get the DeptID from the datarow selected in the cbo using the `SelectedValue` property.  The datatype will match that of the DB Column.

You can do much the same thing using a List(Of Dept) where Dept is a class you build to show the name but allow you to retrieve the DeptID.

Comment: Thank you Plutonix

You have given me some great Ideas ;)

Comment: feel free to click the checkmark next to the answer

Comment: Dont worry Plutonix
I will not hesitate to click the Checkmark once I get the answer I am looking for...
But I still cant find the answer..
I dont think VB has such property like access does